# strncat implementation?

Tags: c, strcat

I'm sorry if this is too entry-level, but I tried implementing the library function of <strike>strcpy</strike>`strncat()` as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strncat (char *s, char *t, int n) {
// malloc to extend size of s
s = (char*)malloc (strlen(t) + 1);

// add t to the end of s for at most n characters
while (*s != '\0') // move pointer
    s++;

int count = 0;

while (++count <= n)
    *s++ = *t++;

*(++s) = '\0';
}

int main () {
char *t = " Bluish";
char *s = "Red and";

// before concat
printf ("Before concat: %s\n", s);

strncat(s, t, 4);

// after concat
printf ("After concat: %s\n", s);

return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs fine...just that it doesn't concatenate at all!

Greatly appreciate any feedback...thanks!

Comment: Try to compile with warnings and debugging info, e g `gcc -Wall -g yoursrc.c -o yourprog` and learn to use the debugger e.g. `gdb yourprog` (you are not understanding well the notion of pointers).

Comment: Thank you...I've never actually used a debugger before, will definitely try it. But in the meanwhile, could you point to a specific place in the function that I'm not implementing correctly?

Comment: No, I can't, there are probably several bugs in your program, and a basic misunderstanding of pointers. Read carefully a good C programming book. Explaining C programming is not possible in a few minutes.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, hey, he's not so bad ;) Look at his [`*s++ = *t++;`]. he-he =)

Comment: `void strncat (char *s, char *t, int n)` does not match the standard function's `char *strncat(char * restrict s1,
const char * restrict s2, size_t n)`.  At least OP has 1 of the 4 types matching (`restrict` issue aside).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you redefine s pointer with your malloc, since you've done it, it doesn't points to your first concatenated string.

First of all function return type should be char*

```
char* strncat (char *s, char *t, int n)
```

After, I think you should create local char pointer.

```
char* localString;
```

use malloc for allocate space with this pointer

```
localString = malloc (n + strlen(s) + 1);
```

and you don't need to make type cast here, cuz malloc do it itself

in fact, you should use your size parameter (n) here, not strlen(t)

and after doing all concatenation operation with this pointer return it

```
return localString
```

Comment: I see...thanks! I'm actually a little unsure about how to use malloc, and since this was how I implemented the strncpy function, I thought I could do the same...didn't cross my mind to create a local string and return it. Really clear...thanks!

Comment: The strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string overwriting the '\0' character at the
       end of dest, and then adds a terminating '\0' character.  The strings may not overlap, and  `the  dest
       string must have enough space for the result`. This is how the library version works, malloc or free is done outside by the caller.

Comment: @dpp yeah, you are right, in classic strncat destination is returned and dest string sure must have enough space. I suggest it's a right decision to make same restriction, but in your own strncat(), I think you can avoid it.

Comment: `char* strncat (char *s, char *t, int n)` matches 2 of the 4 types of the standard function `char *strncat(char * restrict s1,
const char * restrict s2, size_t n)` - better than OP at least.